# reading and writing configuration in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm building a fairly simple Spring Boot application which needs some configuration to be set (and regularly updated as part of it's use). I'd like to create a simple admin interface and first-run wizard to set/update this configuration.

I'd like a way to easily read and write these configuration values within the application and have them persist. I would like to avoid the overhead of a database for 5-10 configuration strings. There is some [good documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) on externalising configuration in Spring Boot but it doesn't talk about how this config could be *updated* and *persisted* by the app.

Options I have come up with:

1. There is a write option with Spring configuration that I'm not aware of (this would be awesome)
2. Don't use the Spring Boot configuration functionality, instead use apache commons configuration (or similar??) to read and write to a file which lives in a location specified by an environment variable
3. as per option 2 but use HSQL, H2 or Derby as a file-based database

Thanks for any suggestions as to how best to achieve this.

Comment: your best option would be to use h2: There is no such thing spring provides out of the box